# Entity ID invalid in Fiware-Orion

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Tried to post an Entitity via the Orion-Context Broker.
Recived the Message:

`Error Message: [INFO]: HTTP response: {"error":"BadRequest","description":"Invalid characters in entity id"}`

Used Entity Id: "urn:ngsi-ld:SensorB-#HP-K12_____"

Invalid Character: "#"

As soon as I got raid of "#" Code worked fine.

Character was not listen here:

https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/forbidden_characters/index.html

> Fortbilden Characters are: < > " ' = ; ( )

Figured it out later on, according to: http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/

> Allowed characters are the ones in the plain ASCII set, except the following ones: control characters, whitespace, &, ?, / and #

Posting to close my to motivated issue on Github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the expected behavior. I mean, as you cite, `#` cannot be used as an identifier (including entity id). Orion is reporting correctly the situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are different sets of forbidden characters. It depends on the field.
But yes, if the documentation says what you report, then perhaps it should be looked over. 
This issue is only about faulty documentation, right?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that as the # char is allowed in URLs / URNs, in NGSI-LD it should be valid and no error should be reported.